# How to operate on defined data type with an user defined data type?

Tags: c++

Here I m trying to overload relational operator. When I m appyling the overloaded function to two objects of class then it is working but when i m applying it to an object and float value then it is giving me error stating that "conversion from 'double'to 'distance' is ambigous".
Pls help.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Distance
{
    int iFeet;
    float fInches;
public:
    Distance(const float);
    Distance(const int = 0, const int = 0);
    bool operator >(const Distance);
};

Distance::Distance(const float p)
{
    iFeet = int(p);
    fInches = (p - iFeet) * 12;
}

Distance::Distance(const int a, const int b)
{
    iFeet = a;
    fInches = b;
}

bool Distance::operator>(const Distance dd1)
{
    if (iFeet > dd1.iFeet)
        return true;
    if (iFeet == dd1.iFeet && fInches > dd1.fInches)
        return true;

    return false;
}

int main()
{
    Distance D(1, 6), D2(1, 8);
    if (D > D2)
        cout << "D is gtreater than D2" << endl;
    else
        cout << "D2 is greater than D" << endl;

    if (D > 5.6)
        cout << "D is greateer" << endl;
    else
        cout << "D is not greater" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `operator>` takes a `Distance` as right hand operand, so if you pass it a `double`, a conversion is needed.

The problem is that you've got two constructos

```
Distance(const float);
Distance(const int = 0, const int = 0);
```

and that the type of `5.6` is `double`. Both constructors are candidates (since they can be called with 1 argument) and neither of required conversion (`double -> float` and `double -> int`) is better than the other. Hence the error saying the call is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Your overloaded `operator >` only works for comparison between two `Distance` objects.

The left-hand-side is already a `Distance`, `D`.

The right-hand-side is a `double`, `5.6`

Your compiler tries to convert the `double` to a `Distance` but there is no suitable constructor. There is a constructor that takes a `const float` and one that takes zero, one or two `const int`s; the compiler cannot choose between the two, hence the error.

You can solve this in a number of ways:

1. Pass a `float`, `5.6f`.
2. Explicitly cast your `float` to a `double`: `static_cast<float>(5.6)`
3. Provide a constructor that takes a `double`.
4. Provide an `operator >` that takes a `double`.
5. Provide a constructor that takes a templated type.
6. Provide an `operator >` that takes a templated type.

Answer (score 0):

Your constructors allow conversions from either `float` (via the first), or `int` (via the second, with a default second argument). You are trying to convert the `5.6`, which is a `double`, for which either constructor is an equally good match; hence the error.

One option is to only use `float` or `int` to initialise it; change `5.6` to `5.6f`.

Another option is to remove the default arguments from the second constructor, so it can't be used for conversion. If you want a default constructor, either add one, or add a default argument to the converting constructor.

Other options are to add more overloads to convert from, or compare to, `double`. That starts to get rather messy though.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is confused because it cannot perform what you ask it to do explicitly, i.e. there is no

`bool operator >(const double);`

But it figures out it can convert `D` into `Distance` implicitly via the constructor you provided, and then use your `bool operator >(const Distance)`. However there are two ways to do it `double -> int -> Distance` or `double -> float -> Distance`. Although, it cannot tell which way is more suitable, hence the error.

You can either provide an overloaded operator for double: `bool operator >(const double);`
 or explicit constructor for double type `Distance(double)`.

I would recommend writing a proper comparison operator, because with constructors there will be an implicit conversion and a temporary `Distance` object created (although in simple cases it might be optimized by compiler).

Also please note two things:

1. You should declare operator operands as references (its is const anyways) i.e. `bool operator >(const Distance&);`. It avoids creating implicit copies of objects. In current state, compiler will need to invoke a copy constructor to for a temporary rhs operand object, because of `copy-by-value` argument passing.
2. Look what would happen if you didn't provide the `float` conversion constructor. Compiler would not have disambiguation. But it would not be good. It would stripe down `double` to `int` and then convert to `Distance`, losing lot of precision. It is wise to use `explicit` keyword when declaring such constructors. So I would recommend to declare it as `explicit  Distance(const int = 0, const int = 0);` just to avoid accidental bugs. They can be nasty to track down. Compilers can easily create strange conversion chains if it's allowed to, which is not always desirable.